# Having some problems showing a query result

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo

I have some data in this mysql table, but it is not showing anything in the html table.
But I am almost sure that the code is not wrong.

(Obs: I am using the "Smarty PHP Template", just to not mix html with php)
Another observation, i did not paste the full code of (pesquisa.tpl).
Imagine that aluno=user and pesquisa=search
**-> pesquisa_aluno.class.php**

```
<?php

class PesquisaAluno {
    private $nome;
    private $sobrenome;
    private $rg;
    private $email;
    private $telefone;

    public function __construct($nome, $sobrenome, $rg, $email, $telefone) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->sobrenome = $sobrenome;
        $this->rg = $rg;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->telefone = $telefone;
    }

    public function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function getSobrenome() {
        return $this->sobrenome;
    }

    public function getRg() {
        return $this->rg;
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getTelefone() {
        return $this->telefone;
    }
}
?>
```

**-> pesquisa.php**

```
<?php

include("classes/pesquisa_aluno.class.php");

$alunos = array();
foreach ($connection->query("SELECT * FROM alunos") as $row) {
    $aluno = new PesquisaAluno($row["nome"], $row["sobrenome"], $row["rg"], $row["email"], $row["telefone"]);
    $alunos[] = $aluno;
}

$smarty->assign('alunos', $alunos);

?>
```

**-> pesquisa.tpl**

```
{foreach from=$alunos item=aluno}
   <tr>
       <td>{$aluno->getNome()}</td>
       <td>{$aluno->getSobrenome()}</td>
       <td>{$aluno->getRg()}</td>
       <td>{$aluno->getEmail()}</td>
       <td>{$aluno->getTelefone()}</td>
   </tr>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Can you insert a `var_dump($alunos)` before the smarty assign?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't include the php file in my handler.php page... That was the mistake.

Comment: @RamonSaraiva - After your `foreach` loop try displaying the content of `$alunos` using `print_r($alunos);`, is it empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class you should return $this->telefone;

e.g.:

```
public function getTelefone() {
    return $this->telefone;
}
```

Edit: did you change it? it said this previously:

```
public function getTelefone() {
    return $telefone;
}
```